# Issue with xarray.open_raterio() img file and multiprocessing Pool

Tags: multiprocessing, python-xarray, rasterio

I am trying to use `mutliprocessing Pool.map()` to speed up my code. In the function where I have computation occurring for each process I reference an `xarray.DataArray` that was opened using `xarray.open_rasterio()`. However, I receive errors similar to this:

`rasterio.errors.RasterioIOError: Read or write failed. /net/home_stu/cfite/data/CDL/2019/2019_30m_cdls.img, band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 190, Y offset 115: Unable to open external data file: /net/home_stu/cfite/data/CDL/2019/`

I assume this is some issue related to the same file being referenced simultaneously while another worker is opening it too? I use `DataArray.sel()` to select small portions of the raster grid that I work with since the entire `.img` file is way to big to load all at once.  I have tried opening the `.img` file in the main code and then just referencing to it in my function, and I've tried opening/closing it in the function that is being passed to `Pool.map()` - and receive errors like this regardless. Is my file corrupted, or will I just not be able to work with this file using multiprocessing Pool? I am very new to working with multiprocessing, so any advice is appreciated. Here is an example of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

def select_grid(x,y):
    ds = xr.open_rasterio('myrasterfile.img') #opening large file with xarray
    grid = ds.sel(x=slice(x,x+50), y=slice(y,y+50))
    ds.close()
    return grid

def myfunction(row):
    x = row.x
    y = row.y
    mygrid = select_grid(x,y)
    my_calculation = mygrid.sum() #example calculation, but really I am doing multiple calculations
    my_calculation.to_csv('filename.csv')

with Pool(30) as p: 
    p.map(myfunction, list_of_df_rows)
```

Comment: Any reason you're doing this and not using dask, which is supported natively by xarray (simply provide the `chunks` argument to [`xr.open_rasterio`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_rasterio.html))? Also, I don't recommend debugging read errors in parallel. Figure out which block is causing errors and open it up/debug it locally. Lastly, if you have a reproducible [mre] getting an error, please include the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) - they're critical to debugging. Thanks!